# Split mailing in separate mailings

Tags: php, email, foreach

I tried to send a mailing to 127 persons. I found out there can only be 99 email-adresses in the bcc-part in one mail.

So I was thinking to split up the array of emails into groups of 40 e.g.

I have an array of emails

```
$emailaddresses = array(
    [0] => email1,
    [1] => email2, ...
```

So I loop over the array and make a list of them:

```
foreach($emailaddresses as $email) {
    $list .= $email.',';
}
```

and then I remove the last ',' and add them to my mail-object:

```
$mail->bcc = substr_replace($list ,"",-1);
```

How can I loop over that array until 40 addresses, send a mail with that list and then continue the loop starting from 41->80 and so on...?

Comment: Do you need to send them as a BCC, or could you simply loop through the list and sent one mail for each recipient?

Comment: why 40? why not all ?

Comment: `array_chunk()` might be useful in this situation

Comment: @mariusnn: that is a possibility as well but I thought the chance of getting errors while sending is lower when you limit the amount of mails instead of the amount of recipients

Comment: `implode` as well (`$to = implode($emails, ';');`

Comment: @Dagon : for some reason I can't send to more then 99 address in one email through @mail(). If I exceed that number no mail is sent at all! At my hosting they said there was a 4000 char-limit in the bcc-field but I stay way beneath that limit. They couldn't give me a proper answer...

Comment: i menat one email each in a loop, then there's no need for the limit

Comment: Thx for you suggestions, I will try to loop over them all and send individual mails

Comment: @Dagon: And when sending out 5000 mails, you want to establish 5000 SMTP-Connections?... Better send in chunks.

Comment: @dognose : you got a point as well. My mailings will never exceed 300 members so it's still acceptable (i think)

Comment: mail() may create 5000 connections but using something like  phpmailer keeps 1 open for the whole loop.

Comment: @AtroX Why not something to the affect of `while($user = array (email1, email2, email3)) { $to = $user(); mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers); }` My syntax could be off, but that's the general idea. That's similar to how I do it using a DB.

Answer (score 3):

First of all; The easiest and probably cleanest way to send mail is to send one for each, meaning all of them have just their own address in the to-field.

```
foreach($arrayOfEmail as $email){
    mail($email, $subject, $message);
}
```

If you must send in chunks, this is my easiest go:

```
$segments = array_chunk($arrayOfEmail, 40);  // Split in chunks of 40 each
for each($segments as $segment){             // For each chunk:
    $mailTo = implode($segment, ',');        // Concatenate all to one recipient string
    (...)                                    // BCC to headers+++
    mail($myEmail, $subject, $message);      // Send mail
}
```

Comment: Yeah, +1. array_chunk is a nice way to go with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think Dagon is right that you really should just send 1 to each person in a for loop and not use the BCC, but here is a shell of a loop to get you started toward the answer:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($emailaddresses as $email) {
    $count++;
    // Use the modulus to see if we are at a multiple of 40
    // Add the address to the BCC however you choose.
    if ($count % 40 == 0) {
        // Send the email and start a new one.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use implode function as

```
$mail_list=implode(",",$emailaddresses)
it will give yor mail address as
email1,email2,email3............... , lastemail
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list like this instead of using array_chunk:

Pre-seeding the array as a test:

```
$someArray = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 368; $i++) {
    $someArray[$i] = $i;
}
```

Logic you would use:

```
$interval = 40;

$segments = floor($i/$interval);

for($i = 0; $i <= $segments; $i++) {
    $elements = join(", ", array_slice($someArray,($i*$interval),$interval));
    // extra logic here; i.e. test/validate addresses
    print $elements;
}
```